# Logotipo Fixado CSS

Tags: css

Queria deixar o meu logotipo fixado só que quando o site é aberto em tela pequena ou tela grande e se ajusta ao tamanho ex:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tela Pequena:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML e CSS do Menu:

```css
#navtoplist {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 389px;
    margin-top:-60px;
    background: transparent;
    voice-family: "\"}\"";
    voice-family: inherit;
}

#navtoplist ul {
    font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 14px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#navtoplist li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navtoplist a, #navtoplist a:link, #navtoplist a:visited {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 6px 0 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 28px;
    background: #000066 ;
}

#navtoplist a:hover{
    background: #99CCFF ;
}

#navtoplist #current a {
    background: #E7E7E7 url(../images/button_current.png) repeat-x; 
    border-color: #E7E7E7;
}

#navtoplistline {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    line-height: 5px;
    background: #dcdcdc ;
    margin-top: -7px;
    margin-bottom: 0px; 
}

/***** NAVIGATION MAIN *****/

#navmainlist {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    width: 200px;
}

#navmainlist li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 2em;
}

#navmainlist li a,#navmainlist li a:link,#navmainlist li a:visited {
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none; 
    text-indent: 10px;
}

#navmainlist li a:hover {
    color: #669933;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none; 
}

#navmainlistline {
    clear: both;
    padding:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    line-height: 2px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 2px 0 15px 0; 
}

/***** NAVIGATION WEBLINKS *****/

#weblinks li
{
    font-size: 90%;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#weblinks a, #weblinks a:link, #weblinks a:visited
{
    color: #999;
}

#weblinks a:hover
{
    color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="navtoplist">
<?


// Si estan definidas las variables de las cookies se procede a mostrar el menu pero no sin antes comprobar que los
// datos de las cookies verdaderamete son del usuario en cuestion.

if(isset($_COOKIE["usNick"]) && isset($_COOKIE["usPass"]))
{

// Se incluyen los archivos necesarios




// Se sanitizan los datos de las cokies

$user=uc($_COOKIE["usNick"]);

// Se selecciona la tabla tb_users donde el usuario es el que se provee en la cookie
require('config.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_users WHERE username='$user'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);        
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
mysql_close($con);
// Se sanitiza de nuevo la cookie

$wask = uc($_COOKIE["usNick"]);

// Se define $wesk como el nombre de usuario de la tabla tb_users

$wesk = $row['username'];

// Se comprueba que el dato de la cookie sea el mismo que el de la tabla, de lo contrario se muestra error, se termina
// el script y se borra la cookie.

if("$wesk" != "$wask") {
echo "Login incorreto.";
?>
<input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="window.location.reload()">
<?
exit();
}

// Se sanitiza la cookie usPass

$wazk = uc($_COOKIE["usPass"]);

// Se define $wezk como el nombre de usuario de la tabla tb_users

$wezk = $row['password'];

// Se comprueba que el dato de la cookie sea el mismo que el de la tabla, de lo contrario se muestra error, se termina
// el script y se borra la cookie.

if("$wezk" != "$wazk") {
echo "Login incorreto.";
?>
<input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="window.location.reload()">
<?
exit();
}

echo"
            <ul>

                <li><a href=\"index.php\">Inicio</a></li>
                <li id=\"current\"><a href=\"surf.php\">Anuncios</a></li>";
// ver si es admicrostrador
require('config.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_users WHERE username='$user'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);        
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
mysql_close($con);
$admicrostrator = $row['user_status'];

        if($admicrostrator == "admin") {

                echo "<li><a href=\"admin/\" target=\"_blank\">Admin</a></li>";
                                        }
echo"
                <li><a href=\"members.php\">Minha Conta</a></li>
                <li><a href=\"advertise2.php\">Anuncie</a></li>
                <li><a href=\"contact.php\">Contato</a></li>
                <li><a href=\"forum\" target=\"_blank\">Fórum</a></li>
                <li><a href=\"logout.php\">Sair</a></li>
            </ul>";


}
else
{

// funcion para sanitizar variables



echo "
            <ul>
                <li><a href=\"index.php?r=".$elref."\">Inicio</a></li>
                <li id=\"current\"><a href=\"surf.php?r=".$elref."\">Anuncios</a></li>
                <li><a href=\"login.php?r=".$elref."\">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href=\"register.php?r=".$elref."\">Registro</a></li>
                <li><a href=\"faq.php?r=".$elref."\">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href=\"advertise2.php?r=".$elref."\">Anuncie</a></li>
                <li><a href=\"forum".$elref."\" target=\"_blank\">Fórum</a></li>
                <li><a href=\"contact.php?r=".$elref."\">Contato</a></li>

              </ul>
";
}

?>

</div>
```

Comment: Para obter uma boa resposta, é melhor você postar ao menos o básico do código que está usando atualmente. Você pode clicar em [edit] embaixo da questão e acrescentar detalhes. De qualquer forma, **[clique aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=media+is%3Aquestion)** e veja se alguma das respostas ajuda.  - com _media queries_ você pode usar definições diferentes de CSS dependendo do tamanho da tela

Comment: Pronto editei, mas o código não tem nada de mais.

Comment: Poste também o HTML e o CSS do menu inteiro.

Comment: Seu código está de difícil legibilidade, você está com dúvida em relação ao alinhamento do logotipo e eu não achei nada referente a ele no código que você colocou aqui. Seria melhor se você isolasse apenas o código relacionado ao logotipo e os elementos que afetam ele.